# Using Enhanced Ecommerce Data Layer for Google Ads Conversion in GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am having trouble using the transaction data layer from Enhanced Ecommerce for the conversion value and transaction ID for Google Ads Conversion with GTM. The data layer is created before the page load so I thought it would be easy to just use ecommerce.purchase.actionField.id and ecommerce.purchase.actionField.revenue but for some reason they are not working for the id and conversion value.

My GTM settings for this Google Ads conversion Code are:
**Conversion ID:** xxxxxxxxx
**Conversion Label:** xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
**Conversion Value:** ecommerce.products.actionField.revenue
**Order ID:** ecommerce.products.actionField.id

Trigger: /checkout/onepage/success (Magento 2)

The variables being used are coming from Enhanced Ecommerce Transaction data layer that is before this tag gets triggered. I know those variables work because I can see them coming in through Google Analytics.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share the relevant GTM settings? How do you try to refer to these variables? What values do you see instead of the expected results?

Comment: Updated @kgrg. Thanks!

Comment: Is the Conversion Value and Order ID provided in GTM as seen in your post, or is it the value of the DataLayer Variables, that are referred in the tag?

Comment: I did a test purchase and the Data Layer for Enhanced Ecommerce gets generated before the page load. The variables for Conversion Value and Order Id are the data layer paths to those values.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference the dataLayer values directly in the tag settings. You need to create variables for these. The easiest for this is to use a Data Layer Variable, similarly to this:
[image]

You will need to use these newly created variables in your tag settings, referenced by their names, e.g. `{{DLV - Ecommerce transaction ID}}` following the example on the image.